# Updating conda in Ubuntu 22.04 has CondaVerificationError

Tags: 22.04, anaconda

I wanted to update the conda environment installet on ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I started with

```
conda update --all
```

The update packages were downloaded. Then the below error occurred.

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for tk located at /home/anaconda3/pkgs/tk-8.6.12-h1ccaba5_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'include/mysqlStubs.h'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

Is there a solution? Thank you.